# Separate connection file in C# and ModbusClient

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

Could you help me with this:

I need to create a connection file to a PLC through ModbusClient, a separate file from the Main, but within the same solution. I have it like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLmOk.png)

And this is the code:

```
namespace HMIOperations
{
    internal class Connection_PLC
    {
        public ModbusClient Connect(ModbusClient modbusClientreturn)
        {

            IPAddress plcIp = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.3.250");
            int plcPort = 49501;

            modbusClientreturn = new ModbusClient
            {
                IpAddress = plcIp,
                Port = plcPort
            };

            //Connect to PLC
            try
            {
                modbusClientreturn.Connect();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Conexion no establecida con el PLC.\n Intenta de nuevo.");
            }

            return modbusClientreturn;
        }

    }
}
```

My question is, how can I use this file in the main and in the other files where I need it. That I have to do?

Comment: I think you don't have to do nothing special... just write `var client = new Connection_PLC()`; then `client.Connect(myModbusClient);`

Answer (score -1):

The problem can be solved like this:

1. Class internal : you can just use the same namespace.
   Try this:

   ```
    Public class Connection_PLC
   ```
2. Replace this solution with the following code that has been tested and my currently used one.

   ```
   using EasyModbus;

    ModbusClient Plc= new ModbusClient();
    private Thread Data_thread = (Thread)null;
    private int[] Registerlist;

    private void connect()
    {    
            Plc.Disconnect();
            ServerIP = "192.168.3.250";
            Plc.Connect(ServerIP, 502);
            this.Data_thread = new Thread(new 
            ThreadStart(this.getmessage));
            this.Data_thread.Start();
     }
    private void getmessage()
    {
            while (Plc.Connected)
            {
                Registerlist= Plc.ReadHoldingRegisters(8,1);//yourregister 

            }

    }
   ```